# Macro for google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I have an issue, I created a google sheet named "test". In this file there is a google slide link and I want when I make a copy of the "test" file that the google slide file also make a copy and update the google slide link.

---

My code :

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu("Custom Actions") //Creates a custom menu item called "Custom Actions"
  .addItem("Clone Files", "cloneFiles") //Adds a clickable button to call the cloneFiles() function.
  .addToUi(); //Displays the new menu.
}


function cloneFiles() {
  var originalSheet = DriveApp.getFileById('E4y2jP1o9sbJvvFLYwzlN0UtlfBfzxX8Y');
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId(); //Get the file Id of the current Spreadsheet.
  var originalSlide = DriveApp.getFileById('r8R3HepThon1dXRK6iPLjwRhSU');
   var sss = SlidesApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/r8R3HepThon1dXRK6iPLjwRhSU') //Opens the spreadsheet with the URL
   var ss = sss.getSheetByName('justificationfile'); 
   var sheet = ss.getSheets()[18];  
   var value = sheet.getRange('B12').getValue().getId();

  var newSheet = originalSheet.makeCopy("New Sheet"); //Create a copy and name it "New Sheet"
  var newSlide = originalSlide.makeCopy("New Slide"); //Create a copy and name it "New Slide"

  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); //Forces the spreadsheets to be updated to their final value.

  SpreadsheetApp.open(newSheet).getSheetByName("justificationfile").getRange("B12").setValue(newSlide.getUrl()); //Then alters the url to the copied file.

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(
    HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<p>New Files Created!<p><ul><li><a href='"+newSheet.getUrl()+"'>New Sheet</a></li><li><a href='"+newSlide.getUrl()+"'>New Slide</a></ul>")
  .setHeight(150)
  .setWidth(150), "Copied files");
}
```

I have a sheet with the id "E4y2jP1o9sbJvvFLYwzlN0UtlfBfzxX8Y" and slide id "r8R3HepThon1dXRK6iPLjwRhSU". I want to clone this sheet file. There is a window named "justificationfile" and in this window in the B12 cell there is a link. Now when I clone the sheet file, I want to clone the slide file (defined by the link in B12 cell) and update automatically the link.

With the code share above there is an error. When I tried with the code that you gave me :

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
      .getSheetByName("Sheet1") //Gets the url on Sheet1
      .getRange("A1")           //On cell A1
      .getValue()).getId()); //Get the file Id
```

I have an error message : "Cannot read property 'getRange' of null"

Comment: Could you clarify what you want? Do you need this sheets and slides files bound to each other (similar to a form and a sheets file)? Are you perhaps distributing this to other people, and are looking for specific features?

Comment: I tried to find a way to modify hyperlinks but it seems the only kind of link that you can modify and links between slides.  I'm hoping @Tanaike will have a better solution later tonight because now I'd like to know too.

Comment: While searching in the Slides API I found this: https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/other#link  I think that may be the solution.  But I'm tapped out tonight.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I want to make a copy of my google sheet and copied also the file attached in this google sheet. But this file is a google slide so i want to update the link in the google sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is rather hard to understand from such a short question so I will elaborate more.

What needs to happen:

1. Copy a Spreadsheet file
2. Find the Slides referenced in the spreadsheet
3. Copy the Slides into a new file
4. On the copy of the spreadsheet, update the link to reflect the new file

To do this, you will use a Apps Script file attached to your sheet. This script will create a custom menu to add the functionality to your Sheets.

There are other ways to do this but this has the ability to keep this functioning for the copies as well. (So copies can make copies of themselves).

Here is the code (with comments):

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu("Custom Actions") //Creates a custom menu item called "Custom Actions"
  .addItem("Clone Files", "cloneFiles") //Adds a clickable button to call the cloneFiles() function.
  .addToUi(); //Displays the new menu.
}

function cloneFiles() {
  var originalSheet = DriveApp.getFileById(
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId()); //Get the file Id of the current Spreadsheet.
  var originalSlide = DriveApp.getFileById(
    SlidesApp.openByUrl( //Opens the spreadsheet with the URL
      SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
      .getSheetByName("Sheet1") //Gets the url on Sheet1
      .getRange("A1")           //On cell A1
      .getValue()).getId()); //Get the file Id 

  var newSheet = originalSheet.makeCopy("New Sheet"); //Create a copy and name it "New Sheet"
  var newSlide = originalSlide.makeCopy("New Slide"); //Create a copy and name it "New Slide"

  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); //Forces the spreadsheets to be updated to their final value.

  SpreadsheetApp.open(newSheet).getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("A1").setValue(newSlide.getUrl()); //Then alters the url to the copied file.

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(
    HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<p>New Files Created!<p><ul><li><a href='"+newSheet.getUrl()+"'>New Sheet</a></li><li><a href='"+newSlide.getUrl()+"'>New Slide</a></ul>")
  .setHeight(150)
  .setWidth(150), "Copied files");
}
```

After adding this to your sheet, anytime a user opens it they will see an extra button:

[image: Custom action Menu]

After clicking our custom action they will see a nice pop-up with the new links:

[image: Result Box]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much I try it this afternoon, thanks !

Comment: After trying to adapt the code, I had the error message : "Cannot read property 'getRange' of null". But I don"t understand the real meaning of this error, I tried to figure out the issue without success.. If you have any helps please

Comment: In which line was this?

Comment: This part : "SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
      .getSheetByName("Sheet1") //Gets the url on Sheet1
      .getRange("A1")           //On cell A1
      .getValue()).getId()); //Get the file Id "

I add the good value but there is an issue

Comment: The name of sheet file is "fichier test", I need to take the link in the "test" sheet in the B12 cell so I had these informations in the code but nothing

Comment: Could you post a new question with your update code and what you have tried so far?

Comment: Yes I created new question with more details